# Salesforce Milestones Timer when changing Entitlement with different Business Hours

Tags: servicecloud, casemilestone, entitlements, businesshours

I have an interesting use case and I would like to tap into your expertise to see the best way to achieve this (without code ). I'll try to keep it as simple as possible.

- We have two teams: Customer Service and Managed Service.
- Each team uses different Business Hours.
- I've set up only two Milestones, First Response and Resolution.
- I've set up two Entitlement Processes, 'Customer Service Entitlement
  Process' and 'Managed Service Entitlement Process' (maybe I can do it with one?)
- Customer Service Entitlement First Response Milestone is 30 minutes
  and Resolution is 60 minutes.
- Managed Service Entitlement First Response Milestone is 60 minutes
  and Resolution is 120 minutes.

**What I want to achieve:**
A new case is always created with the Customer Service Entitlement, which has a 30 minute First Response Milestone. If the user changes the Entitlement (lookup) to Managed Service, which has a First Response of 60 minutes and different Business Hours, it should deduct any time already used while it was under Customer Service Milestone - AND obey the new Business Hour.

**Example:**
New Case comes into Customer Service and has a 30 minute First Response Milestone. After 10 minutes, the user changes the Entitlement to Managed Service.

Manage Service's Business Hour only starts an hour from when the case Entitlement changed. Thus, the Milestone is paused for 1 hour.

When the Managed Service Business Hour starts, Manage Service entitlement has a first response of 60 minutes, but because 10 minutes was already used during the Customer Service Entitlement, the remaining time should now be 50 minutes.

**What is currently happening?**
The Milestone resets to 60 minutes.